# Прописная буква

Tags: прописная-строчная

Объясните, пожалуйста, в каких случаях слово музей, дом-музей, дом-усадьба пишутся с прописной буквы. Везде по-разному. В учебнике русского языка читаю: музей им.Л.Н.Толстого (слово музей с маленькой), Музей народного творчества (с большой). А как же дом-музей. Подходит ли его правописание под правило: с прописной буквы пишется первое слово зрелищных предприятий и учреждений культуры (Дом-музей Чехова). А почему дом-музей "Усадьба Рукавишниковых" слово дом с маленькой. Я совсем запуталась. Объясните, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Дом-музей Чехова-официальное название в документах, поэтому первое слово с большой буквы (как Русский музей, Музей искусств народов Востока, Дом художников, Центральный дом художников).

Музей им. Л.Н.Толстого может быть в любом городе, музей - это не имя собственное, это родовое понятие, вот если бы у него было название (в кавычках), это было бы именем собственным.

Дом-музей "Усадьба Рукавишниковых" - имя собственное в кавычках, а дом-музей - родовое понятие, не имя собственное.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в неформальных текстах допустимы разные трактовки некоторых наименований: со ссылкой на официальное название музея (библиотеки, дома-музея) как организации и без неё.

"Крупный чиновник такой-то посетил в этом городе обе верфи и местную библиотеку имени Чехова".

"На обсуждение бюджета Министерства культуры были приглашены представители Государственной Третьяковской галереи и Библиотеки имени Ленина."

Во втором примере - ссылка на конкретную и широко известную библиотеку в Москве, видовое наименование с заглавной буквы указывает именно на неё. Ещё возможны случаи, когда слово "музей" в полном официальном наименовании пишется с маленькой буквы (в средней части полного наименования), но при укороченной ссылке на него же может оказаться с заглавной. Например, Государственный мемориальный музей обороны и блокады Ленинграда в неформальных текстах может именоваться "Музеем обороны и блокады Ленинграда", хотя, видимо, допустимо и "музей Обороны и блокады Ленинграда". Многое зависит от степени смысловой условности наименования: даже в неофициальных названиях (Музей чертей - отдел музея Чюрлёниса в Каунасе) может оказаться полезной заглавная буква в видовом наименовании.

Answer (score 0):

2. С прописной буквы пишется (помимо первого слова и собственных имен) начальное слово той части, которая сама по себе употребляется в функции того же названия, например: Государственный Исторический музей (ср.: Исторический музей), Государственный Литературный музей (ср.: Литературный музей), Государственная Публичная библиотека имени М.Е. Салтыкова-Щедрина (ср.: Публичная библиотека имени М.Е. Салтыкова-Щедрина), Государственная Третьяковская галерея (ср.: Третьяковская галерея), Государственный академический Большой театр (ср.: Большой театр), Московский Художественный академический театр (ср.: Художественный театр), Центральный Дом журналиста (ср.: Дом журналиста).